# How to transform the img to smaller size in TS or CSS

Tags: html, image, angular

Is there any way to resize the image and reduce it's weight in Angular/TS or in CSS? I mean something like 'picture' tag in HTML 5.1.

Comment: _Picture_ tag don't change the source size.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the image on the frontend won't change it's weight, as the full image has to be retrieved from the server anyways. The 'picture' tag isn't able to do this either.
The only thing coming close to what I believe you want to achieve is this Angular directive I found online:

https://github.com/oukan/angular-image-compress

This also only compresses on the client side and won't change the weight of the image retrieved in the first place.